# Is there a way to create a dialog box that has a text field and will return the string of the text field?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a dialog that will ask for a file name.  Is there a way to create a dialog that has a TextField and will return the string in it? All the documentation I found deals with dialog boxes that have buttons and returns a number.

Comment: Yes, there's [a way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: Are you using Swing or JavaFX?

Comment: You can create a new class and extend JDialog, there you can create and add your own components. Here you can find some examples, you can also use the link provided above which is a good start point as well: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jdialog/java-jdialog-example/
If the only thing you need is a dialog to get a String from a textfield, then the answer below is a good option as well.

Comment: All subclasses of `TextComponent` and `JTextComponent` have a `getText()` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextComponent.html#getText%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is simple, so let's take a simple approach:

```
String filename = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "File name?");
```

[Here's more info about JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)